# Replace s string in Ruby by gsub

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have a string

```
path = "MT_Store_0  /47/47/47/opt/47/47/47/data/47/47/47/FCS/47/47/47/oOvt4wCtSuODh8r9RuQT3w"
```

I want to remove the part of string from first `/47` using `gsub`.

```
path.gsub! '/47/', '/'
```

Expected output:

```
"MT_Store_0  "
```

Actual output:

```
"MT_Store_0  /47/opt/47/data/47/FCS/47/oOvt4wCtSuODh8r9RuQT3w"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Did you understand the question now?

Comment: @kumaresan do you want to remove the whitespace before `/47` as well?

Comment: does the string always match the given pattern ("what_i_need<space>what_i_dont_need") 

is using gsub mandatory?

Comment: @Stefan No,i dont want to remove the space. But remove all the other string from '/47'

Comment: @MErose, I don't think there is empirical evidence to support that conclusion. Some readers don't care if the OP shows his/her attempts; some will answer only when the question interests them. If the OP has come close to a solution, or wants to know why code doesn't work, then yes, it's good--maybe essential--to see the code. If, however, the OP doesn't know where to begin, we shouldn't force the production of some artificial failed attempt. Moreover, readers *never* complain when a high-rep member asks a question without producing code that doesn't work.

Comment: Why limit solutions to those using `gsub`? If you are just interested in removing parts of a string, I suggest you frame your question without reference to `gsub`, though you may still use `gsub!` in your example. This may be what's termed an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

```
path.gsub! /\/47.*/, ''
```

In the regex, `\/47.*` matches `/47` and any characters following it.

Or, you can write the regex using `%r` to avoid escaping the forward slashes:

```
path.gsub! %r{/47.*}, ''
```

Comment: You could use the `%r` literal to avoid escaping forward slashes: `gsub! %r{/47.*}, ''`

Answer (score 0):

If the output have to be `MT_Store_0`

then `gsub( /\/47.*/ ,'' ).strip` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions that employ neither `Hash#gsub` nor `Hash#gsub!`.

**Use [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-index)**

```
def extract(str)
  ndx = str.index /\/47/
  ndx ? str[0, ndx] : str
end

str = "MT_Store_0  /47/47/oOv"
str = extract str
  #=> "MT_Store_0  "

extract "MT_Store_0 cat"
  #=> "MT_Store_0 cat"
```

**Use a capture group**

```
R = /
    (.+?)  # match one or more of any character, lazily, in capture group 1
    (?:    # start a non-capture group 
      \/47 # match characters
      |    # or
      \z   # match end of string
    )      # end non-capture group
    /x     # extended mode for regex definition

def extract(str)
  str[R, 1]
end

str = "MT_Store_0  /47/47/oOv"
str = extract str
  #=> "MT_Store_0  "

extract "MT_Store_0  cat"
  #=> "MT_Store_0  cat"
```